# ASP.NET Core - Cannot set default value '1' of type 'System.Int32' on property 'MerchantStatus'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, I have this enum:

```
    public enum MerchantStatus : byte
    {
        Inactive = 0,
        Active = 1
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Merchant : AuditableBaseEntity 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Merchant Name is required")]
    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account Number is required")]
    [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }


    public MerchantStatus? MerchantStatus { get; set; } // 0=Inactive, 1=Active  Active/Inactive --default value

    [Display(Name = "Charge Mode")]
    public ChargeMode? ChargeMode { get; set; } //0=Fixed Or 1=Percentage
}


        modelBuilder.Entity<Merchant>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(m => m.MerchantStatus).HasDefaultValue(1);

        });
```

I got this error:

> Cannot set default value '1' of type 'System.Int32' on property 'MerchantStatus' of type 'System.Nullable`1[Helpers.EnumList+MerchantStatus]' in entity type 'Merchant'.

How do I resolve this?

Thaanks

Comment: have you tried `.HasDefaultValue(MerchantStatus.Active)`

Comment: The error tells you that the int32 value of 1 is not the right type as it should be of type `MerhcantStatus?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cast your integer by replacing

`.HasDefaultValue(1);` with `.HasDefaultValue((MerchantStatus)1);`

or better - use the defined enum `.HasDefaultValue(MerchantStatus.Active)`